# How can I hide ticket status in hybris?

Tags: java, status, sap-commerce-cloud

How to hide ticket status in hybris? OTTB in hybris there is 3 statuses **(open, in process, close** ). I add my custom status **Rejected**. Logic which hybris do is when create one ticket from storefront, then when login in backoffice as 'CustomerSupportAgent' in ticket tab when click on created ticket I can see 3 statuses ( **In process, close, and my custom status Rejected** ), and when I change status from **In process** to **Close** then I see 2 statuses **Close** and **Reopen**. I want when my status is **In proceess** and click **Rejected** to see **Rejected** and **In process or Reopen**, but **Close** status to be not visible.

Hybris do spring mapping to make this visible.

```
<alias name="csTicketStateTransitionMap" alias="ticketStateTransitionMap"/>
    <util:map id="csTicketStateTransitionMap">
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.NEW"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
    </util:map>
```

When I add my logic for **Rejected**

```
<alias name="csTicketStateTransitionMap" alias="ticketStateTransitionMap"/>
    <util:map id="csTicketStateTransitionMap">
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.NEW"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>

//here I add like hybris logic when click Rejected to see Reopen or In process but not Close
<entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.REJECTED"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.CLOSED"/>
            </key>
            <util:list>
                <util:constant static-field="de.hybris.platform.ticket.enums.CsTicketState.OPEN"/>
            </util:list>
        </entry>
    </util:map>
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

What I actually do:

I use B2B recept and I have my custom addon 'customerticketingaddon' which requires-extension name="customerticketingfacades"

in my **customerticketingaddon-items.xml** I add my custom status in CsTicketState

```
<enumtype code="CsTicketState" autocreate="false" generate="false" dynamic="true">
            <value code="Rejected"/>
</enumtype>
```

Then in my **cusomerticketingaddon-spring.xml** I do the mapping which I showed above.

Comment: Did you try giving different map name? May be it is overridden by original.

Comment: I tried it so it still don't work

Comment: @mkysoft Hybris documentation write : ''Override or change this map to implement your own business rules. This follows the standard for defining a Map in Spring.''

https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c7258ff86691014b485bfd58e138ed3.html

Comment: Did you define it in correct module/scope?

Comment: @mkysoft I update my question. Yes do everthing correct I think so

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure that you are using backoffice spring context to define your bean.

Hybris-way to extend map beans is to use Map Extender backoffice functionality - https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/94ac56a0aa9f486490bbe1251d994457.html#loio83afe1e428384fa881d687b0baa6ea48

cng:map-extender provides an ability to put and remove map entries.

Take a look at the example from `ruleenginebackoffice-backoffice-spring`

Original bean definition

```
    <alias name="defaultBackofficeCronJobHistoryIncludes" alias="backofficeCronJobHistoryIncludes"/>
<util:map id="defaultBackofficeCronJobHistoryIncludes" key-type="java.lang.String"
          value-type="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
    <entry key="syncProcesses">
        <bean class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
            <property name="jobTypeCode" value="#{T(de.hybris.platform.catalog.model.SyncItemJobModel)._TYPECODE}"/>
        </bean>
    </entry>
    <entry key="excelImportProcesses">
        <bean class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
            <property name="jobTypeCode" value="#{T(com.hybris.backoffice.model.ExcelImportJobModel)._TYPECODE}"/>
        </bean>
    </entry>
    <entry key="auditReportGeneratorProcess">
        <bean class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
            <property name="cronJobTypeCode" value="#{T(de.hybris.platform.auditreport.model.CreateAuditReportCronJobModel)._TYPECODE}"/>
        </bean>
    </entry>

</util:map>
```

Extended using

```
    <cng:map-extender bean="backofficeCronJobHistoryIncludes" xmlns:cng="http://www.hybris.com/cockpitng/spring">
    <cng:put key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
        <entry key="ruleEngineProcesses">
            <bean class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.CronJobHistoryInclude">
                <property name="jobTypeCode" value="RuleEngineJob"/>
            </bean>
        </entry>
    </cng:put>
</cng:map-extender>
```

Comment: I use B2B receipt

Comment: Just configure your extension/addon to support backoffice configuration.

Update `extensioninfo.xml` with

`<extension>
    <meta key="backoffice-module" value="true"/>
</extension>`. Then add `<extensionname>-backoffice-spring.xml`. This spring configuration will be merge into backoffice web context.

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. OOTB hybris have 3 ticket statuses ( Open , In process, Close ). I add my custom status. Now have 4 status ( Open, In process, Rejected, Close ). That what I want is when I click status "Rejected" after that when click again on drop-down with statuses to see only "Rejected and In process" and in documentation write if you want to change visibility of statuses override or change this mapping https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c7258ff86691014b485bfd58e138ed3.html